# Test for informational efficiency

Tags: statistical-significance, forecasting, f-test, efficiency

I need to compare one benchmark models regarding their "informational efficiency" against three other models. From my search I can now say, that this usually refers to the question how well a model is utilizing the information until t to forecast t+h.

I have found mincer-zarnowitz test, to test each model. But how to test for information efficiency for

- Model Benchmark against model A
- Model Benchmark against model B
- Model Benchmark against model C

?